# JSF: Clear the DataTable when no records found?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a strange issue. I have a search criteria and i have a datatable which displays the results.

The search functionality works fine. Below is the issue.

I enter some search criteria i click on search button the records get displayed. Fine.
Again i enter some search criteria for which there are no records the datatable should get cleared.But the issue is the old record itself is getting displayed. What can be the problem

Below is my java code:

```
public void results(TestItem[] TestItemTOArray, TestForm TestForm, boolean isNewSearch, CarService carService) throws Exception {
        if (viewBean instanceof TestViewBean) {
            TestViewBean = (TestViewBean) viewBean;
        }
        TestRowForm[] TestRowFormArray = this.convertToTestRowForm(TestItemTOArray, TestForm, isNewSearch, carService);
        if(TestRowFormArray.length > 0)
            TestForm.setTestRowForm(TestRowFormArray);
        if(TestRowFormArray!=null){ 
            TestForm.setTestRowForm(TestRowFormArray);
            TestForm.setTotalRows(TestRowFormArray.length);
        }
    }
```

JSF:

```
<rich:dataTable
        value="#{testController.testForm.testRowForm}"
        rows="#{testController.noOfRecordsToShow}" var="resultRow" noDataLabel="No Result Found"
        headerClass="ColumnHeader" styleClass="DataTable" rowKeyVar="itc"
        style="width:980px;" id="dtTable">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should clean up data source for data table in case when result set is empty too.

Comment: thanks for your response.. But how do i cleanup my dataTable. as you can see I do set my array which comes in result as [] but the datatable is unchanged. :(

Comment: Debug it and check return of `convertToTestRowForm` in specified case. Plus check if datatable was re-rendered after method call.